# What are the use of interfaces with type parameters?

Tags: java, generics, interface

What are the use of interfaces with type parameters? what are they really used for? is my understanding correct.
Let's say I have this interface

```
public interface Moveable <Person>{
    void move(double x, double z);
}
```

Does this mean that only objects that are Type Person can use /implement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the typical pattern and in your case the type parameter isn't doing anything. Here's a better example.

```
public interface Movable<T> {
    T move();
}
```

Now your code will return the type that the implementer specifies instead of you just saying move always returns object or some other more generic class.

Edit:

```
public MyMover implements Movable<Truck> {
    public Truck move(){
        return new Truck();
    }
}
```

You can't really restrict implementers of your interface to be certain types. You can restrict it [by package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html) if you want. Maybe an abstract class would work better for you.

Comment: How can I restrict other objects using this interface? should I add an upperbound? like T extends comparable? wherein only classes or objects that implements comparable will be able to use this interface? can you provide an example with your created interface?

Comment: @user962206: time to read a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)?

Comment: @jjathman is correct. As is, specifying the type in your interface doesn't make for very scalable code, if you decide later that you want to broaden its use. You don't need to `restrict its use` necessarily OP, just control what uses it through your code.

Comment: I added a pretty contrived example for you but Java interfaces don't really do what you are trying to make them do.

Answer (score 1):

`Does this mean that only objects that are Type Person can use implement this?`

No, not exactly, a generic is used in an interface is just the same as if it were used in a normal class. It specifies what type of object the interface will contain / manipulate.

Think of how you declare an `ArrayList`. You need to specify which type of object that `ArrayList` will contain, since it deals with objects of each type differently.

In your declaration of the interface you are saying that the classes that implement this interface will only hold / manipulate objects of type `Person`.

For more information on Generics, check out this link:

[Oracle: Generics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html)